# C# CS1503 Datagridview argument 1 cannot convert to int

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, datagridview

I am looking to write a series of records from a datagridview into sheet.  Most of the code is not giving errors but the following code is causing an error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to 'Int'.  The error is on the "r"

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in orderlistgrid.Rows)
                {
                    string ccno = orderlistgrid.Rows[r].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    string ccname = orderlistgrid.Rows[r].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    string proj = ProjectList.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    string suppname = orderlistgrid.Rows[r].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                    string suppcode = orderlistgrid.Rows[r].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                    string ordno = orderlistgrid.Rows[r].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                    string jobcode = JobList.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    string ddate = orderlistgrid.Rows[r].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                    string comm = orderlistgrid.Rows[r].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                    string ordval = orderlistgrid.Rows[r].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                    string var = orderlistgrid.Rows[r].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
```

I hunted high and low to research this (including referencing other C# projects from VS2010) and can't see to trouble shoot this one out.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try `string ccno = r.Cells[0].Value.ToString();`  Though to be fair, there's probably a better way to do this, like data binding perhaps.

Comment: too easy, it has worked a treat